# g++ and c++0x specification support

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++11

although it's been said that the support for c++0x new features in g++ are in experimental mode, many gcc developer claimed that you can use most of the new features in your codes and get the program to work.

but when I try to compile this simple program it results in segmentation fault. Why?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void my_thread_func()
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(my_thread_func);
    t.join();
}
```

g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -o run main.cc

Comment: What version of gcc are you using ?

Comment: As someone not immersed in C++, the way the thread object is implicitly started by constructing it is surprising :-)

Comment: I was checking out C++0x features in Microsoft VS 2010. They have support for several: auto keyword and type inference, lambdas, decltype(), nullptr, exception_ptr for passing exceptions between threads, static_assert(), rvalue references and move constructor/assignment operators and perfect forwarding. Also there are template classes std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr, and other related.

However, #include <thread> and std::thread are not supported yet. This is very disappointing as would have been nice to do portable threading code across VC2010 and g++ using the C++0x standards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I linked the executable with pthread library and it worked! I did not see any missing shared library dependency (ldd), but seems like std C++ library implementation on Linux uses pthread internally.

```
g++ thread.cpp -o thread -Wall -std=c++0x -lpthread
```

Comment: Oh my god, How much silly i am. 
Thanks Sumant, It works well with -lpthread switch

Comment: I thought that there would be a separate implementation of c++0x thread in g++, but as you said it currently uses posix thread library.